# How can I get values of a control from the user-defined control in the parent form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have created a user defined control which contains a panel and in the panel is a label and a textbox. Now, in my parent form there is a flowlayout panel. I am adding my user-defined control to the flowlayout panel.

[image: user-defined control]

[image: flowlayout panel]

Here is the code which I am using to get the control values, but it's always giving me checked listbox control values:

```cs
// Here 'panel_Attribute' is my parent form panel to which I have added the controls 
Control.ControlCollection listControls =  panel_Attribute.Controls;
foreach (Control attributeControl in listControls)
{ 
  if (attributeControl is Control)
  {
    log.Debug("attributeControl Values are attributeControl attributeControl.Name" +
        attributeControl.Name + ", Value: " + attributeControl.Text);

    attributeList.Add(((PHShowAttributeControl)attributeControl).
        ProbeRawProjectTaskAttributeEvent);
    //attributeList.Add(GetControlValues());
  }
}
```

Comment: `(Window.Controls[x] as UserControl).Control.Property` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you add your UserControl to your ParentForm the Designer creates it and you have direct access to it.

For example:

```
myUserControl.Enable = false;
```

Your ParentForm doesn't have to know something about your Controls inside the UserControl. Just spend your UserControl some Properties. Let's say you have a Textbox for the Name from Customers:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
   public string Name
   {
      //Inside your UserControl you can access your Controls directly
      get{return textBoxName.Text;}
      set {textBoxName.Text = value;}
   }
}

public class MyForm : Form
{
   //This set the Text in your UserControl Textbox.
   myUserControl.Name = "Mr. Example";
}
```

I hope this will help you.